Expo Router Tab Behavior on Different Device Sizes (Tablet menu bar looks diffrent from phone size)
I am using Expo Router for my application, particularly utilizing tabs for the menu bar. I have a specific styling requirement where icons should appear above the title on smaller phone screens. However, on tablets, the behavior changes to displaying the icon on the left and the title on the right. I would like to maintain the same styling behavior on tablets as well.
Versions:
Expo: ^50.0.14
Expo Router: ^3.4.8
Menu Bar Layout Code:
return (
  <Tabs
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: true,
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTintColor: COLORS.pureWhite,
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: SIZES.xLarge,
        paddingBottom: SIZES.xSmall,
      },
      headerBackground: () => (
        <LinearGradient
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }}
          colors={[COLORS.lightPurple, COLORS.darkPurple]}
        />
      ),
      tabBarStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 90 : 70,
        paddingBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 10 : 0,
      },
      tabBarLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: SIZES.extend.regular,
        fontFamily: 'Urbanist_600SemiBold',
      },
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: COLORS.darkBlack,
      tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.brightPurple,
    }}
  >
        <Tabs.Screen
        name="userProfile"
        options={{
          title: 'Profile',
          headerTitle: 'Profile Settings',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }: { focused: boolean }) => {
            return <NickName isMenuBar={true} active={focused} />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Broadcast Hub',
          title: 'Go Live',
          tabBarItemStyle: {
            flex: 1.3,
            height: 45,
            borderRadius: 50,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: isDisabled
              ? COLORS.lightGray
              : COLORS.brightPurple,
          },
          tabBarIconStyle: { display: 'none' },
          tabBarLabelStyle: {
            fontSize: SIZES.extend.medium,
            marginTop: 0,
            marginLeft: 0,
            fontWeight: '600',
            color: COLORS.pureWhite,
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
          },
        }}
        listeners={() => ({
          tabPress: () => {
            handleGoLiveClick();
          },
        })}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="statistics"
        options={{
          title: 'Statistics',
          tabBarIcon: () => {
            return <Statistics />;
          },
        }}
        listeners={() => ({
          tabPress: ev => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            handleStatisticsClick();
          },
        })}
      />
    
  </Tabs>
);

Request:
Could you please assist me in achieving consistent styling behavior for tabs on both phone and tablet devices? Currently, the styling changes on tablets, and I would like to maintain the icon-above-title style as seen on phones. Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance.
I expected the menu bar to looks like in mobile (icons above the title)
